# How to install apache24 and php55 from macports?

Tags: macports

I need apache24 because of some features what introduced in 2.3. And (unfortunately) need php too.

So decided to install the next ports:

- apache24-devel
- php55
- and php55-apache2handler

For some reason the php55-apache2handler builds apache22. Is it possible to have an apache24 `variant`?

What are the steps to installing apache24 with php? I need compile everything compiled manually from sources.

As an alternative should I migrate to "homebrew"? Is here some macports based solution?

*ps: using 10.9*

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in the php55-apache2handler port: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/41478